# Preventing UICollectionViewCell animated appearance when presenting UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uikit, uicollectionview

When a user does some action, I need to pull a `UICollectionView` from the bottom up to a certain height. Since that new state is totally optional, the collection view is created just before being presented that way. The animation from bottom to top is performed using changes to NSLayoutConstraint's `constant` property and a call to `[view layoutIfNeeded]` in some animation block.

The problem is that, doing things that way makes the cells appear in an undesired way: they expand from their top-left corner to their specified size. I would like the collection view to appear and have all of its cells already laid out in their final size and appearance.

I'm aware of things like UIView's `setAnimationEnabled:` method, but I can't seem to find how and where I should use that (if that's the way to go).

I guess the problem is due to the collection view cells being added to the view hierarchy just before the animation block that contains the call to `[superview layoutIfNeeded]`. This probably leads UIKit to think that it should also animate *those* changes to the layout. If that's the case the solution would probably be something along the way of excluding from the animation, specific changes to the view hierarchy.

Comment: Running into some similar bugs in my application--for example, when I boot it in simulator the entire app's screen expands outward from the top-left corner, and certain pieces of text sometimes "jump" up to the left corner of their superview and then animate down into place. Similarly I do several animations with constraints in different parts of my app. Would appreciate an answer to this question :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Expanding from the top left corner is typically a symptom of calling `layoutIfNeeded` in an animation block when the original view has never been laid out. You're basically animating the initial layout pass, where all subviews have started at CGRectZero.

To solve it you need two things:

- Ensure the constraint you're editing is related to the *position* of the collection view, not the size. By this I mean that you're not presenting your collection view by changing its height from zero to the final value.
- Call `layoutIfNeeded` on your view before you edit the constraint, then call it again in the animation block after you've made the change. This way you're only animating the change you've specified to the constraint, rather than the entire layout.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! For reference, what I turned out to do was to create a low-priority constraint that would make the collection view height equal to the window height, call `layoutIfNeeded`, setup higher priority constraint that would override the previous one, and perform the animation! And it worked beautifully!

Comment: Taking advantage of priorities is a great idea! I'm about to write something similar myself and I usually keep references to various constraints around, but I'll try it your way this time.

Comment: Thank you for this idea of calling layoutIfNeeded twice

Answer (score 1):

I've been in this problem for around 3 days and finally got a solution.
Simply I added the animation block to be called after a very tiny timer

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 7 , options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }){ _ in}
```

will be

```
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.changeConstraint()
    }

private func changeConstraint(){

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 7 , options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }){ _ in}
}
```

See the magic :)