# collection view cells visibly resize when being displayed the first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, collectionview

i have a collectionView which works very well except for one odd feature.  When the view with the collectionView first appears, the collectionView cells seem to all briefly transform to the correct size.  It looks like they are animating their size change to the correct size.  This is a visible animation which I do not want.  I just want the cells to appear correctly sized.

I load all the data for my collectionView in viewDidLoad.  I have tried reloadData in various places (viewWillAppear, viewDidLayoutSubviews) but it doesn't make any difference.  Even without ever reloading the Data it is still initially presenting with the visibly transforming cells.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this could be your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17330785/1068243

Comment: wow.  thanks so much for that.  I just added one line: collectionView.layoutIfNeeded() in my viewWillAppear and everything works perfectly now.  thanks!